# Count Title and Post Characters

Tags: php, functions

I need to get a total count of characters for post titles and post text characters. Are there any build-in WordPress functions available for that? My posts are paginated so the numbers for post text count it would have to come from DB?

Using these numbers I would like to build a function that will feed my Google Tag Manager dataLayer with things like:

```
if($postCaharacters < 1000) {
    echo "GTM_POST_CHARACTERS:'Under 1000'";
}
```

And so on.

**UPDATE - FINAL WORKING CODE**

```
function countWords() {
    global $post;
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $decode_content = html_entity_decode($content);
    $strip_shortcode = strip_shortcodes($decode_content);
    $strip_wp_tags = wp_strip_all_tags($strip_shortcode, true);
    $countwords = str_word_count($strip_wp_tags);
    $number = $countwords;
    if ($number > 3000 || $number == 3000) {
        return '3k+';
    } elseif ($number > 2500 || $number == 2500) {
        return '2.5k-3k';
    } elseif ($number > 2000 || $number == 2000) {
        return '2k-2.5k';
    } elseif ($number > 1500 || $number == 1500) {
        return '1.5k-2k';
    } elseif ($number > 1100 || $number == 1100) {
        return '1.1k-1.5k';
    } elseif ($number > 800 || $number == 800) {
        return '800-1.1k';
    } elseif ($number > 500 || $number == 500) {
        return '500-800';
    } elseif ($number > 200 || $number == 200) {
        return '200-500';
    } else {
        return '<200';
    }
}
```

Comment: I added an example of each function I used, maybe that helps you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this function [`wp_strip_all_tags`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_strip_all_tags).

```
strlen( wp_strip_all_tags($post->post_content));
```

With that you get rid of all the HTML tags.

Just a little extra detail, you might want to strip the shortcodes, too. You can use this function [`strip_shortcodes`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/strip_shortcodes)

You will end up with something like this:

```
 strlen( wp_strip_all_tags(strip_shortcodes($post->post_content)));
```

To convert the encoded entities to the corresponding string value you could use the PHP function `html_entity_decode`.

Example.

```
" " &lt;/S&lt;&gt;;
is converted to
" " </S<>;
```

TEST:

```
//CODE
    var_dump($post->post_content);
    var_dump(wp_strip_all_tags($post->post_content, true));
    var_dump(html_entity_decode(wp_strip_all_tags($post->post_content, true)));
    var_dump(html_entity_decode(strip_shortcodes(wp_strip_all_tags($post->post_content, true))));

 //RESULTS

string 'áé´r´díó' ñ   " " &lt;/S&lt;&gt;;   a

[gallery]' (length=59)

string 'áé´r´díó' ñ   " " &lt;/S&lt;&gt;;   a [gallery]' (length=56)

string 'áé´r´díó' ñ   " " </S<>;   a [gallery]' (length=47)

string 'áé´r´díó' ñ   " " </S<>;   a ' (length=38)



//CODE
var_dump(strlen(html_entity_decode(strip_shortcodes(wp_strip_all_tags($post->post_content, true)))));

var_dump(strlen(html_entity_decode(wp_strip_all_tags($post->post_content, true))));

var_dump(strlen(wp_strip_all_tags($post->post_content, true)));

 //RESULTS

int 38
int 47
int 56
```

As I was using `var_dump` each string has it's lenght, but I added the results of the call to the `strlen` function anyway.

Comment: Thanks! That's actually working very well! I turned the whole thing into function but for some reason it always returns 0. I tested it with out WP functions functions and it works. See update.

Comment: @user3088202, where are you using that function? try to add this line `var_dump($post);`

Comment: Its in my header.php file at the very top. Should I put it in the functions folder and call it in the page later?

Comment: you could add the function to the `functions.php` file, or not. But in the first line of the function add this `global $post;`, or pass the content of the post as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in assuming that `$post->post_content` contains tags and other not textual entities like shortcodes. You can use `strip_tags` to get rid of the tags but you will probably want to expand the shortcodes first.
resulting in something like

```
$count = strlen(strip_tags(do_shortcode($post->post_content));
```

And it will still give you the wrong results depending on whether spaces quotese etc need to be counted.

Comment: I see what you saying about quotes and etc. Right now -> Don't == Don&#8217;t so it counts extra chars. I will have to str_replace before everything else. Is there a good list of characters that I can just pop into that function?

Comment: I am actually not sure that the "text" in the DB is converted to HTML therefor you don't need to worry about converting &#8217 to ', but if I am wrong you can use html_entity_decode which is a php function.

Comment: I tried using that function on the get_the_title() but it still returns &#8217.

Comment: @user3088202, maybe this is what you are looking for `html_entity_decode`

Comment: That is the one I used but it still didn't get rid of anything.